# how to test a function which calls 2 other functions with jest and enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using `react-dates` component in my react project and `onDatesChange` is a function which is dispatching actions to `redux` store two times, can someone help me in testing this function with `jest` and `enzyme`..

This is `DateRangeComponent` imported from `react-dates`.

```
<DateRangePicker
   startDate={this.props.filters.startDate}
   startDateId={this.state.startDateId}
   endDate={this.props.filters.endDate}
   endDateId={this.state.endDateId}
   onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
   focusedInput={this.state.calenderFocused}
   onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
   showClearDates={true}
   numberOfMonths={1}
   isOutsideRange={() => false}
/>
```

And this is my function which is dispatching two actions to the `redux` store.

```
onDatesChange = ({ startDate, endDate }) => {
  this.props.dispatch(setStartDate(startDate));
  this.props.dispatch(setEndDate(endDate));
};
```

How can I test this function in this form. I know, I can test it easily if I refactor it to `mapDispatchToProps`, which I don't wanna do. thanks

Comment: what exactly are you trying to test? What have you tried?

Comment: @MikeBell I want to test `onDatesChange` is being called with `startDate` and `endDate`. But when I make `dispatch` mock function and pass it as a `prop` in component then expecting the outcome of dispatch returns two functions call (which is right) but i dont know how to test them. expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('what should i write here?');

Comment: Also `expect(dispatch)` gives me function calls happening inside the body of function. But I also wanna test `onDatesChange` is being called with `startDate` and `endDate`. which I dont know how to do..